# How to run granger-test for original stationary and transformed stationary time-series in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I have three time-series of daily frequencies named *a*, *b*, *c*. I have transformed the three time series via *zoo* and then run [three tests to check for stationarity](https://rpubs.com/richkt/269797) also detailed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149335/interpretation-of-var-and-causality):

- Ljung-Box is <0.01 for all
- ADF hovers around 0.01 for all (0.0104, 0.01395, 0.0151), so under 0.05
- KPSS test is <0.01 for two and 0.06 for one

This tells me that *c* is stationary and *a* and *b* are not. To transform the two non-stationary time series to stationary, I use diff()

```
diffa <- diff(a)
diffb <- diff(b)
```

So now I have the time series *c*, *diffa*, and *diffb*. *c* has the length 230, *diffa* and *diff* 229. As they have different lengths, I can't run *grangertest()* on *c*, *diffa*, and *diffb*.

My questions:

- As far as I understand, I should not use diff() on an already stationary time series although this would solve the different lengths problem. Correct?
- How can I run grangertest() on the three time series? Should I add 0 as the first value for the two now-stationary time series? That strikes me as wrong. Adding NA as first value doesn't work as this throws an error.
- Or am I missing something entirely here?

Edit: I also ran the Johansen-Procedure

```
###################### 
# Johansen-Procedure # 
###################### 

Test type: trace statistic , with linear trend 

Eigenvalues (lambda):
[1] 0.2870433 0.2059927 0.1364341

Values of teststatistic and critical values of test:

           test 10pct  5pct  1pct
r <= 2 |  26.70  6.50  8.18 11.65
r <= 1 |  68.68 15.66 17.95 23.52
r = 0  | 130.25 28.71 31.52 37.22

Eigenvectors, normalised to first column:
(These are the cointegration relations)

                  a.l2  c.l2        b.l2
a.l2       1.000000000  1.00000000  1.000000000
c.l2  0.002389741 -0.01354087 -0.009186882
b.l2      -0.721484628  0.63371350 -5.025730289

Weights W:
(This is the loading matrix)

                a.l2 c.l2      b.l2
a.d       -0.4943852 -0.1442216 0.03055074
c.d -28.8624865 22.6674082 5.20934270
b.d        0.3205697 -0.1668201 0.05236327
```

Edit 2:
VECM output from tsDyn

```
AIC 7310.527    BIC 7364.995    SSR 107996319896
Cointegrating vector (estimated by 2OLS):
   a       c         b
r1  1 -0.0003824692 -0.5213095


                 ECT                  Intercept               a -1               c -1          b -1               
Equation a      -0.5926(0.1377)***   8.7668(12.0209)         0.1257(0.1237)      0.0011(0.0006)*     -0.2109(0.0768)**   
Equation c 14.7790(21.2262)     -26.1263(1852.6566)     1.3814(19.0588)     -0.1389(0.0852)     -0.8560(11.8419)    
Equation b      0.1636(0.2013)       2.6051(17.5698)         0.0168(0.1807)      0.0035(0.0008)***   -0.3475(0.1123)**
```

Comment: The mistake is that you have to work with all the series with first difference. For example, in a job I did, all the series turned out to be stationary with the first difference. (You work with all the series differentiated or not | VECM -VARM)

Comment: Thanks! I ran a VECM model with tsDyn but, honestly, am a bit stuck with the interpretation and/or where to go from there (See output above). My basic idea was to run a Granger test to see whether one time series predicts the other. I am very unclear on what VECM does in that context.

Comment: In most papers the VECM output is not interpreted only the significance, what is important is the causality and the impulse response functions (there may be an analysis on the variance decomposition)

Comment: My problem stems from not fully understanding which way the significance goes: a -> b or b -> a? a -> c or c -> a? If that makes sense (from above's results)

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=on7VvErrVLA) can help u.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great video! This goes back to my question on how to deal with the difference in length between a, b, c. Before making A and B stationary, a, b, and c all have the length 230. After making them stationary with diff() diffA and diffB have length 229, while C is still at 230. When I want to merge() or cbind() the three time series in preparation for VAR() the different lengths are an issue. Can I just remove the first entry for C? Or should I create a diffC?

Comment: You should create a diffC

Comment: Thanks! I was under the assumption that I was not allowed to use diff() on a stationary time series. But if I can, then that solves it! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, could you give as correct the solution I posed below? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VECM works with non-stationary series so you will have an order of integration to be stationary I(1).[image]

https://pdf4pro.com/view/vector-error-correction-models-215587.html